# How many AdMob ads can i put in our android app

Tags: admob

How many AdMob ads can i put in our android app? Can i use unlimited Admob ads (Banner ads, Interstitial ads, Rewarded video ads, Native ads) in only one app and this app upload in play store?

Can i use Admob without uploading app in playstore?

Comment: You can use admob ads as much as you wish. The ads will be shown in your app without publishing in the Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

All admob unit are used in your apps with publish on playstore. but when you click on the ads by you and you friends...

you account may suspended without Notification.